# Using Node to save JSON data from Twitter API

Tags: json, node.js

I have JSON data stored in the variable 'data'.

I want to write this to a text file.

Can I do this with Node? I am a beginner

Comment: Yes, it's very basic. What have you tried so far? surely you have googled the issue before coming here, what attempts have you made?

Comment: I'll be willing to help if you provide us with more details, what you've tried so far, and show a bit more interest in your own question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this NPM module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile

```js
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
 
var file = '/tmp/data.json'
var obj = {name: 'JP'}
 
jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, function (err) {
  console.error(err)
})
```